# Violation of Impersonation policy and i'm getting the message stating remove the metadata that could mislead users

Tags: impersonation

I recently made one app and going to published in google console but after an hour i'm getting the message your app is rejected due to violation of impersonation policy.
can someone tell me what does it mean?Is i'm changing the meta-data in my manifest file or change the App's meta-data?what does it meant?Is that meta-data is copyrighted?I'm using the icon of other app Is this is my fault?

please give me solution to this problem i'm in problem or tense by this ,thanks in advance!!

//this is my manifest file

      ...

```
    <meta-data android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey" android:value="ee23b7943cd81d7bd7b59c0653ac380b2600f9b4" />
</application>
```

//this is my gradle file

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.glomadrian:MaterialAnimatedSwitch:1.1@aar'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.+'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
repositories {
    maven {url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
}
repositories{
    maven {url 'http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven'}
}
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.3@aar'){
    transitive = true;
}
```

[This is the message from google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L9y0.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that your app will use Google Firebase or something related to crashlytics.